# r - simpler code than this? -- rgraphviz plot

Tags: r, optimization, plot, reshape

I don't see a direct way to exclude non-connected terms from an Rgraphviz correlation plot.  I developed a convoluted way to remove the terms that won't be in the plot. (I'm new to r.)  Does Rgraphviz actually have this option, and/or is there less convoluted code to get the needed subset of terms?

```
terms1=findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq=30)
# Find the subset of terms1 where every term in terms1 has a 
# correlation of at least 0.7 with at least one other term in terms1, 
# as they occur in the dtm.
c1 = cor(as.matrix(dtm))
c2 = c1[terms1,terms1]
c2[c2 == 1] <- NA 
c2[abs(c2) < 0.7] <- NA 
library(reshape)
c2 <- na.omit(melt(c2)) 
c2 = as.data.frame.array(c2)
c2 = unique(c2[,2])
# Rgraphviz must be loaded.
plot(dtm, terms=c2, corThreshold=0.7)
```

This code has a potential flaw - if two terms happen to have a correlation of 1.0.  The line is in there to remove a terms correlation with itself.

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? Is `dtm` part of any package available from public repositories perhaps?